# jquery works only offline in chrome, online not at all

Tags: jquery, html, css, firefox, google-chrome

I am still new to jquery and could use a little help here :-)
This code works when I am offline in Chrome, once I try to use it in IE9 or Firefox it won't work. So I **uploaded** the site and now it won't even work in Chrome.

I get an error message in Firefox and IE which tells me "event is not defined" line 8 which is --> event.preventDefault();

What can it be? wrong links?
In html they are added like this :

The problem is solved
This line solved the problem :

```
 $('.hidden_nav ul li a').click(function(event){
                event.preventDefault();
```

It's the function(event). And I had left an empty function()

Thanks to everyone

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        //Get size of docuement and apply to div grid

        var height = $(document).height();
        $('.theGrid').css('height',height);

        // Slide Down hidden Content
        $('.hidden_nav li a').click(function(){
                event.preventDefault();
                var selected = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
                var thisone = $('#'+ selected);

                $('.hidden_content').slideDown(200);
                thisone.slideDown(200);
                thisone.addClass('online')
                $('.bubble').fadeIn(100).delay(2000).hide(300);

            });

            $('.close_btn').click(function(){
                $('.hidden_content').slideUp(200);
                $('.online').hide().removeClass('.online');
                $('.bubble').hide();

            });

        //Design Process // a few $ animations
        $('.step_img').mouseover(function(){
            var sel = $(this).next('h4').text().toLowerCase();
                thisone = $('#' + sel);
                thisone.children('p').slideDown(100);
        });
       $('.step_img').mouseout(function(){
            var sel = $(this).next('h4').text().toLowerCase();
                thisone = $('#' + sel);
                thisone.children('p').delay(1000).slideUp(400);
        });


        // Slider  (Nivo Slider Plugin) effects
         $('.slider').nivoSlider({
                effect:'random',
                startSlide:2,
                directionNav: true,
                pauseOnHover: true,
                pauseTime: 6000,
            });
    });
```

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: Only from firefox, telling me : event is not defined
and once online, chrome and firefoy say : Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Window] is not a function

Comment: @Skooz - Which line is the error pointing to?

Comment: @JasCav at line 3 event is not defined and line 10 $ is not a function

Comment: @JasCav Here is the website http://schausgilles.com/tfa/ 

The links on your top left point to the non javascript page instead of showing the right div, and the the other qjuery elements are missing like a slider  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Double check that your file is correctly loading the jquery library.  If you are using relative paths locally, make sure they are the same on the server.

Comment: Hi, path is okay and  jquery works. The code works now in Chrome, I changed the click functions name... But IE and FF still not willing to do what I want

Comment: Based on the site you provided above, it looks like you are calling the "nivoSlider" but I do not see where you are loading the script for that plugin.

Comment: I dont use it at the index page, but on the others

Comment: But your script tries to call it on the index page in http://schausgilles.com/tfa/js/my-script.js, my guess is that once the javascript interpreter hits that error, nothing else fires.

Comment: What happens once you click on a link on the top? Are you getting redirected to a page called info.html ?
And try it in Chrome if you can please

Comment: No still not working :Still tells me  "event is not defined" line 8 which is --> event.preventDefault();

Comment: For me, when I click on the links in the top left, a pane slides down with various information, contact for contact, your picture for "Me", etc... is this not what you are looking for?  The lines on the left produce some strange behavior of jail like bars over the entire page...

Comment: So it's kind of working for you and yes the line are my grid ;-)
In which browser did you try?

Comment: The latest version of Chrome.

Comment: Yes works in Chrome.. the other browsers open the info.html page once they click on the link top left. So it's the preventDefaul which isn't working?